# Sidekiq - Prevent worker from being executed in specific machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, distributed, sidekiq

I'm working on a Rails project that uses Sidekiq. Our Sidekiq implementation has two workers (WorkerA, that reads queue_a, and WorkerB, which reads queue_b). One of them has to be executed in the same server the Rails app is and the other one in a different server(s). How can I prevent WorkerB from being executed in the first server, and vice versa? Can a Sidekiq process be configured to run just specific workers?

EDIT:
The Redis server is in the same machine the Rails app is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, here is the way to start sidekiq with options

```
nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q queue_a queue_b -c 5 -e #{Rails.env} -P #{pidfile} 2>&1 &
```

you can start sidekiq with specific workers

you can run `nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q queue_a -c 5 -e #{Rails.env} -P #{pidfile} 2>&1 &` to execute only WorkA

to distinguish different workers on different servers, just do like below:

```
system "nohup bundle exec sidekiq -q #{workers_string} -c 5 -e #{Rails.env} -P #{pidfile} 2>&1 &"

def workers_string
  if <on server A> # using ENV or serverip to distinguish
    "queue_a"
  elsif <on server B>
    "queue_b queue_b ..."
  end
end

#or you can set the workers_strings into config file on different servers
```

Comment: AFAIK, the `-q` parameter is to create additional queues, not to specify workers

Comment: sorry, you can start sidekiq with `-q queue_a` , this way only exxcute WorkA

Answer (score 7):

Use a hostname-specific queue.  config/sidekiq.yml:

```
---
:verbose: false
:concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - default
  - <%= `hostname`.strip %>
```

In your worker:

```
class ImageUploadProcessor
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: `hostname`.strip

  def perform(filename)
    # process image
  end
end
```

More detail on my blog:

http://www.mikeperham.com/2013/11/13/advanced-sidekiq-host-specific-queues/

Comment: Perhaps I should've waited for the Sidekiq's author answer :) However, I think @Zoker's approach will do, as `queue_b` is not gonna be processed by just one host. The idea is that, as `queue_b` is used for long time consuming jobs and can grow quickly, we want to scale up and create new workers to process that queue. Thanks for such a good gem @Mike

Comment: Either way, as long as you find something that works for you.  Thanks!